# Get updated column value and old value ON Update ,insert Trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I m new to Triggers. I have table 'Sample' and 'SampleAudit'. I created Trigger 
For Update and Insert. The trigger is as follows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ss].[SampleTrigger]
   ON  [ss].[Sample] 
   FOR INSERT,UPDATE

AS 
    declare @fullname varchar(200);
    declare @addressline1 varchar(200);
    declare @addressline2 varchar(200);
    declare @landmark varchar(200);
    declare @city bigint;
    declare @state bigint;
    declare @pin varchar(50);
    declare @country varchar(100);
    declare @auditaction varchar(100);


    select @fullname=i.fullname from inserted i;
    select @addressline1=i.addressline1 from inserted i;
    select @addressline2=i.addressline2 from inserted i;
    select @landmark=i.landmark from inserted i;
    select @city=i.city from inserted i;
    select @state=i.state from inserted i;
    select @pin=i.pin from inserted i;
    select @country=i.country from inserted i;

   if UPDATE(@fullname)
    set @auditaction= 'updated FullName from'+oldval+' to '+ new value ;

    if UPDATE(@addressline1)
    set @auditaction= 'updated addressline1 from'+oldval+' to '+ new value ;

    if UPDATE(@addressline2)
    set @auditaction= 'updated addressline2 from'+oldval+' to '+ new value ;

    if UPDATE(@landmark)
    set @auditaction= 'updated landmark from'+oldval+' to '+ new value ;



insert into [ss].[SampleAudit]
(FullName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,LandMark,City,State,Pin,Country,auditaction)
values(@fullname,@addressline1,@addressline2,@landmark,@city,@state,@pin,@country,@auditaction)
```

Here each time updating a new raw is inserting to Audit table. So

```
    if Update(fullname)
    if UPDATE(@addressline1)  
    if UPDATE(@addressline2)  
    if UPDATE(@landmark)
```

all are updating. So how can i get which and all fields are updated ? and old and new value for all updated fields.

```
1. I need to track which and all fields updated.
2. and from which value to which value it is updated ?
```

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or **multiple** rows. Your trigger is inherently broken - you're not even guaranteed that each of your separate assignments to variables will be retrieving values from the *same* row, and you're ignoring all other rows. Try to create an `insert...select` statement that references `inserted` in the `FROM` clause instead.

Comment: I will get latest updated values. trigger is correct only.  i dont have any issues in trigger....

Comment: No, if I write `INSERT INTO Sample (fullname) SELECT 'abc' UNION ALL 'def'`, your trigger will only pick up *either* `abc` or `def`. Not both. Similarly, for an update that affects multiple rows, you'll only pick up values from one row. `inserted` should be treated as a *table* that can contain multiple rows (or no rows). Triggers fire once per statement, not once per row.

Comment: I dont have any issue like this......

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ss].[SampleTrigger]
   ON  [ss].[Sample] 
   FOR INSERT,UPDATE

AS 
    declare @fullname varchar(200);
    declare @addressline1 varchar(200);
    declare @addressline2 varchar(200);
    declare @landmark varchar(200);
    declare @city bigint;
    declare @state bigint;
    declare @pin varchar(50);
    declare @country varchar(100);
    declare @auditaction varchar(100);


    select @fullname=i.fullname from inserted i;
    select @addressline1=i.addressline1 from inserted i;
    select @addressline2=i.addressline2 from inserted i;
    select @landmark=i.landmark from inserted i;
    select @city=i.city from inserted i;
    select @state=i.state from inserted i;
    select @pin=i.pin from inserted i;
    select @country=i.country from inserted i;

    Declare @Type int
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) and 
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
               SELECT @Type = 'U'
    Else
         SELECT @Type = 'I'

    if (@Type = 'U')
    Begin
        set @auditaction= 'updated FullName from'+ (Select d.fullname From  deleted  d) +' to '+ (Select i.fullname from inserted i) ;
        insert into [ss].[SampleAudit] (FullName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,LandMark,City,State,Pin,Country,auditaction)
        values(@fullname,@addressline1,@addressline2,@landmark,@city,@state,@pin,@country,@auditaction)

        set @auditaction= 'updated addressline1 from'+(Select d.addressline1 From   deleted  d)+' to '+ (Select i.addressline1 from inserted i) ;
        insert into [ss].[SampleAudit] (FullName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,LandMark,City,State,Pin,Country,auditaction)
        values(@fullname,@addressline1,@addressline2,@landmark,@city,@state,@pin,@country,@auditaction)

        set @auditaction= 'updated addressline1 from'+(Select d.addressline2 From   deleted  d)+' to '+ (Select i.addressline2 from inserted i) ;
        insert into [ss].[SampleAudit] (FullName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,LandMark,City,State,Pin,Country,auditaction)
        values(@fullname,@addressline1,@addressline2,@landmark,@city,@state,@pin,@country,@auditaction)

        set @auditaction= 'updated addressline1 from'+(Select d.landmark From   deleted  d)+' to '+ (Select i.landmark from inserted i) ;
        insert into [ss].[SampleAudit] (FullName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,LandMark,City,State,Pin,Country,auditaction)
        values(@fullname,@addressline1,@addressline2,@landmark,@city,@state,@pin,@country,@auditaction)
    End

    If (@Type= 'I')
    Begin
        Set @auditaction = 'Insert'
        insert into [ss].[SampleAudit] (FullName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,LandMark,City,State,Pin,Country,auditaction)
        values(@fullname,@addressline1,@addressline2,@landmark,@city,@state,@pin,@country,@auditaction)
    End
```

Comment: I have 23 columns in my table. Then 23 rows will insert saying that fullname updated from old to new value, etc.....

Comment: By doing this , i will get old and new values, but if i wont update all fields except fullname, 4 rows will insert to the audit table .